# Salesforce showing error:Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement

Tags: apex, community

```
Opportunity opp  = [SELECT Id, **.Id, **.Id from Opportunity where Id = :opportunity.Id LIMIT 1];
if (opp != null) {
// My code
}
```

Its showing error on line opp  `if (opp != null) {`.
I dont understand the meaning of the error shown by salesforce.

Comment: Ok understood, thanks. My method was returning a map, but I didnt add a return statement, as I was building the method, it was a compile time validation error.

Comment: Great. Added it as an answer so you can accept since it turned out to be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method needs to return something from each logical path. If you do not intend to return a value change the return type to void for example inside your If if you have a return what if opp == null you need a return statement outside of the if in that case as well